# How to filter list with linq for sub list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following classes:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerId;
        public string CustomerName;
        public List<CustomerOrder> Orders;
    }

    public class CustomerOrder
    {
        public string OrderName;
        public string Account;
        public string PassFail;
    }
```

What I am trying to do is I need to get only Customer records that have had zero PassFails = "F" for that account.  So for example if I have CustomerId = 1 and two Orders for Account = "1000" one PassFail = "P" and one = "F".  I don't want the Customer record in my result set.  So I have the following so far:

```
//get accounts where any order failed
var failedAccounts = customers.SelectMany(s => s.Orders)
                    .Where(w => w.PassFail == "F")
                    .GroupBy(g => g.Account)
                    .Select(g => new
                    {
                        Account = g.Key
                    });
```

I am stuck at this point as I am trying to get my customers list where all orders have passed for the account.  Hope this makes sense.   I want to still keep the Order record as is I need to know if one of the orders did pass but at a later stage I need to filter out the Customer records.  Thanks all

Comment: `customers.SelectMany` is selecting all the `Orders`. You should use `customers.Where` if you want to select `Customers`.

Comment: It's still confusing to me the result you're trying to achieve with the `GroupBy`

Comment: FYI if `PassFail` can have only two values, perhaps it should be a `bool` type named `Passed` (or `Failed`). Otherwise, it may be better named as `"Grade"` or `"Result"`, or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
customers.Where(s => s.Orders.All(o => o.PassFails == "F"))
```

and then add anything you want

Answer (score 0):

`customers.SelectMany()` in the sample code is selecting all the `Orders` from the customers (but not the customers themselves). We can use `customers.Where()` to select `Customers`, and then to filter on accounts that have ***any*** order whose `PassFail` value is `"F"`, we can use the `Any` extension method (from `System.Linq`):

```
var failedAccounts = customers.Where(s => s.Orders.Any(o => o.PassFails == "F"));
```

Conversly, if we want to find the customers whose orders are ***all*** passed, we can use `All`:

```
var passedAccounts = customers.Where(s => s.Orders.All(o => o.PassFails == "P"));
```